# SQLContext: '<package or class name>'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working with PySpark version 2.4.7

In PySpark, I am generating a Spark context and SQLContext like following:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark_context = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)
```

In my **SQLContext instance** I see there are *_jvm and _jsc* instance variables.

When accessing **_jvm** I see a weird thing:

```
# dir(sql_context._jvm)
['<package or class name>', 'SparkConf', 'Tuple2']
```

What is 'package or class name'?
I am trying to mock an instance of SQLContext but it seems really complex.
I have read somewhere that this is related to dynamic stuff...
Can I get more explanations?

Regards,